# Setting a new contentSize to a UIScrollView causes it to scroll back to point x:0 y:0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

In my app I have some logic that changes the `UIScrollView`'s `contentSize` dynamically. The problem I'm running into is that when I change the contentSize it sets the `contentOffset` to `CGPointZero` or something like that.

I guess you can't set `contentSize` to be in the middle of the `UIScrollView`. Any ideas on how to get this to work?

In other words I want to change the `contentSize` of my `UIScrollView` half way and keep its `contentOffset`.

thanks in advance,

fbr

Answer (score 2):

In my application, i had a `UIViewController` which had a `UIScrollView` as its root subview. That scrollView contains a `UIView` which acts a a container for a `UITextView` i had embedded.

Entering a long enough string would cause the textView to expand, subsequently changing the `contentSize` of the scrollView causing it to reset it's content offset to 0. Looking at the stack trace i was able to see `_adjustContentOffsetIfNecessary` attempts to adjust the content offset **immediately** after a contentSize change.

I created a subclass of `UIScrollView` that blocks `_adjustContentOffsetIfNecessary` initial attempt to adjust the offset.

```
class CustomScrollView: UIScrollView {

    private var oldContentSize: CGSize = .zero

    override var contentOffset: CGPoint {

        set {
            if oldContentSize == contentSize {
                super.contentOffset = newValue
            } else {
                super.contentOffset = super.contentOffset
                oldContentSize = contentSize
            }
        }

        get {
            return super.contentOffset
        }
    }
}
```

When the contentSizes are the same, we adjust the offset as normal. If it differs, we keep the offset the same and update oldContentSize to its new size so the next time around it's receptive to changing its offset.

Answer (score 0):

As you've already seen, you can't do this by changing `contentSize`, but you can fake it by changing the `contentOffset` and moving your subviews around. An example of this in the `DTInfiniteGridView` class of Daniel Tull's [DTKit library](http://bitbucket.org/danielctull/dtkit/src/tip/DTInfiniteGridView/DTInfiniteGridView.m).

Comment: I'm not familiar with this library. Could you tell me where in the code he is faking it contentSize with contentOffset.
This is what I'm trying to do. I'm developing a data table where you can see data in columns and rows just like an excel spreadsheet. The reason why I want to set the contentSize dynamically is to constrain the user to vertical and horizontal scrolling only. So if I detect a Vertical scroll in the UIScrollView I set the contentSize where the width is equal to the width of the UIScrollView's frame and I maintain the height.

Comment: Why can't you use UIScrollView's directionalLockEnabled?

Answer (score 0):

`setContentSize:` of UIScrollView will set its contentOffset( `_adjustContentOffsetIfNecessary`, an internal method is called,which does the mysterious offset change on your scrollview.)

One way to set the required content offset  is to do `setContentOffset:reqiredOffset animation:NO` on the scrollview.
(requiredOffset is calculated for new contentSize).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just trick this by saving your current `contentOffset` and after you set the new `contentSize`, you can just use the `setContentOffset:animated:` to return the scroll where it was. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know about which is the method will used,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    srcv.contentSize = ?;
}
```

Here what will come and replace with "?" to scroll the simulator